# Using one store for multiple elements of the same type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

Let's say I have two controller-views - `ItemsContainer`, `Item` and a store `ItemsStore`, which stores items list. When items list changes because of some action, store emits change, and both views get their state from `ItemsStore`.

`ItemsContainer` calls `getItems` and rerenders items list. `Item` calls `getItem` method with its id, and rerenders itself.

Now, what is the simpliest way to let me have multiple `ItemsContainer`'s on screen?

I can rewrite `ItemsStore`, so that it stores its data in a map `id -> storeData`, but that would mean that every `ItemsStore` method will need another parameter `storeId` also passed to it.  `getItems()` becomes `getItems(storeId)`, `getItem(itemId)` becomes `getItem(storeId, itemId)` which looks too ugly. Actions will also require passing `storeId`.

[Another way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23597375/3445165), as I understood, is making a store, which would manage `ItemsStore`'s data, and reinitialize it, calling `STORE_UPDATE` action.

The problem with this method is, if we have two(A and B) `ItemsContainer`'s, and the active container is A, so that `ItemsStore` contains items which are rendered in A, container B will still listen to `ItemsStore` changes. I can add a check if it's the active container in `ItemsContainer.onChange` method, but I'm not sure that's the way it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could add your components here so we can see how you're organizing them. That being said, I'm going to take a stab at how I would structure this anyway.

If I were to make a react/flux app that had multiple lists containing items, each with separate items I'd do something like this:

Top-level controller-view component: ItemsApp
Child of ItemsApp: ItemsList
Child of ItemsList: Items

ItemsApp would be the component that retrieves state from the store. In the store I would have a listOfItems which is an array of objects, each object representing an individual item, with a "name" and "category". Let's say some items have a category of "red" and others "blue".

So, itemsApp gets it's state from the store and passes all of the items down to the individual ItemsList components, like so:

```
render: function() {
   var red = "red";
   var blue = "blue";

     return (
        <div>
          <ItemsList items={this.state.listofItems} category={red} />
          <ItemsList items={this.state.listofItems} category={blue} />
        </div>
     )
 }
```

Then, each ItemsList would take the list of items and filter it to look for only items that match the category it would pass down, like so:

```
render: function() {
     var category = this.props.category;
     var itemsToRender = this.props.items.filter(function(item) {
        return (
             item.category = category
        )
     });

     return (
          <div>
            <Items items={itemsToRender}/>
          </div>
     )
  }
```

Then, in the Items component:

```
render: function() {
     var displayedItems = this.props.items.map(function(item) {
        return (
               <li className={item.category}>{item.name}</li>
        )
      });

     return (
         <ul>
          {displayedItems}
         </ul>
     )
   }
```

Depending on how you want to structure your code, you could also use map inside of ItemsList on your newly filtered list, returning some JSX for each item, passing down the name and category of the item, and then your Item component would do nothing but render a `<li className={this.props.category}>{this.props.name}</li>`, or whatever you want your markup to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case, I can't store items of separate categories in the same array. I was looking for solution, with which I'll be able to use my  ItemsStore, with some small changes.